# Xamarin.Forms - A List of Fonts in XAML

Tags: list, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am trying to construct a `List<Xamarin.Forms.Font>` in my XAML, but I can't seem to get it right:

What I am doing (this populates an array (not desired) with empty fonts):

```
<x:Array x:Key="Fonts" Type="{x:Type Font}">
    <Font>Font1</Font>
    <Font>Font2</Font>
</x:Array>
```

What I actually want to achieve (not sure how):

```
<x:List x:Key="Fonts" Type="{x:Type Font}">
    <Font>Font1</Font>
    <Font>Font2</Font>
</x:List>
```

Then in my code-behind, I want to access that list of fonts:

```
var (List<Font>)Resources["Fonts"];
```

I've tried adding a generic, `Systems.Collections.Generic`, namespace from the `mscorlib` assembly.
 and using `<generic:List>...</generic:List>` (compiler cannot find List within that namespace).

Any advice on achieving this?

Comment: Why does it have to be typed as a Font? Essentially the FontFamily that you're setting in XAML is a string and to get it to work cross-platform you might even need different strings per platform.

Comment: @StevenThewissen - I am implementing a font manager to provide a more consistent look across platforms. And I need to pass a Xamarin.Forms.Font to that font manager and it will return me a device appropriate scaled font.